# Flutter - Add a container or box underneath a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a box (hopefully can assign a onPressed function to it later on). I tried adding a container below the dice but the box goes right next to second die but I actually need it to be below the two dice.

I have tried Listview too but no luck. Here's my code:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
    child: Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          changeDiceFace();
        },
        child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          changeDiceFace();
        },
        child: Image.asset('images/dice$rightDiceNumber.png'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
));
```

}
}

Thanks in advance!

I am very new to Flutter and the coding world :D

[image: add a box below dice]

Comment: Where is the code for the container below the dice?

Comment: Hi Gretal, thanks for responding. The container code didnt work so I took it out.

Comment: if you add how you are trying to add a container, then where you are doing a mistake it can be said...

Comment: Thanks gretal. Sorry for the confusion, I will try to explain my question better next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you want is this.

If you want to trigger an event on click, you can use InkWell or GestureDetector.

If you want to change the state on click, use `setState`.

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: size.width * 0.4,
                height: size.height * 0.2,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Image(image: AssetImage('imagePath'),),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: size.width * 0.1,
              ),
              Container(
                width: size.width * 0.4,
                height: size.height * 0.2,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Image(image: AssetImage('imagePath'),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: size.height * 0.05,
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: (){ changeDiceFace(); },
            child: Container(
              width: size.width * 0.6,
              height: size.height * 0.1,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 7.0),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                'Click',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: size.width * 0.1),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jungwon!! I will give it a try